# Django, Modelform not rendering

Tags: python, django, render, modelform

I created a basic Modelform in django but my form does not render.

**tasks.html**

```
<table class="...">
        <tr>
            <th>Function</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form }}
                    <button type="submit">Execute</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**models.py**

```
class Tasks(models.Model):

    #Task module 

    function_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    script_location = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='')
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

from .models import Tasks

class Tasks(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ['function_name','script_location']
```

**views.py**

```
class Tasks(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = Tasks()
        return render(request, '.../tasks.html', {'form': form})
```

I except to see two text fields, but i only see the 'Execute' button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: avoid name clashes. Add suffixes to your form and view.

You named the *model* `Tasks`, the *form* `Tasks` and the *view* `Tasks`. Here the `Tasks()` call in your view will resolve to that view, so indeed:

```
class Tasks(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = Tasks()
        return render(request, '.../tasks.html', {'form': form})
```

Here you thus simply create a new `Tasks` object (the one that is a subclass of `View`).

I *strongly* recommend to rename your classes:

1. a *model* usually has *no* `Model` suffix, so you can keep this `Task` (singular);
2. a *form* can use a `Form` suffix, so `TaskForm`; and
3. your view can be renamed to `TaskView`.

After renaming, you thus can rewrite your view to:

```
class TaskView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = TaskForm()
        return render(request, '.../tasks.html', {'form': form})
```

Here however, it looks that you basically implement a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView), like:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView

class TaskView(CreateView):
    model = Task
    fields = ('function_name','script_location')
    template_name = '.../tasks.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('certain-view')
```

This will for a GET request render the template with a `form` in the context. It will impelement a POST request as well that will create a model object and save it to the database, and then make a redirection to the *`certain-view`*. So it will implement a lot of boilerplate code for you.

Comment: the CreateView did it for me. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

change your forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Tasks
class TasksForms(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = ('function_name','script_location',)
```

add url in your apps urls.py

```
path('your_url/', views.TaskView, name='task'),
```

change your views.py

```
def TaskView(request) :

    def get(self, request):
        form = TasksForms()
        return render(request, '.../tasks.html', {'form': form})
```

don't forget to add action of your form in tasks.html

Comment: But now you turn the `TaskView` into a funciton-based view, with an inner method `get`. Not only will that `get` method *not* be called (unless you call it explictly), it would also result in a useless inner method (such that it can not be pickled for example).